# why 'event.currentTarget.siblings(element).innerHTML' doesn't work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

If the related part of the html is like this:

```
<table id="mainProds">
    <tr id="food"> 
        <th> Foods </th>
        <td> Cake </td>
        <td> Pudding </td>
        <td> Burger</td>
        <td> Panta </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = "clothes">
        <th> Clothing </th>
        <td> Fatua </td>
        <td> Kamizs </td>
        <td> Pants </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p id=”abcd”> </p>
```

And then my script is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(“td”).click(function(event){
$(“#abcd”).text(event.currentTarget.innerHTML).prepend(event.currentTarget.siblings(“th”).innerHTML);
});
});
```

If i click on the second td of the first row, the output is: Pudding

When the first statement(`event.currentTarget.innerHTML`) works, why doesn’t the second(`event.currentTarget.siblings(“th”).innerHTML`)? How can I proceed like this? If I click on the second td of the first row I want the output:
**Food** pudding

Comment: Try `$(event.currentTarget).siblings('th').html()`.  event.currentTarget is a native DOM element

Comment: Yes, i had tried this too. but the result is same.

Comment: You sure?  This works here http://jsfiddle.net/bexf2qkz/3/

Comment: Thanks. It worked because you added 'html()' at the end, and i missed it to read. i tried with '.innerHTML' at the end. Thank You.